# Detecting running pg_dump conflicting with schema changes

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, heroku

I use Heroku PostgreSQL and their PGBackups for my production environment. I have found, for reasons that I'm not quite clear on, that at least some schema changes do not run correctly during the time that the backups are happening.

According to these [Heroku docs](https://help.heroku.com/7U1BTYHB/how-can-i-take-a-logical-backup-of-large-heroku-postgres-databases), it seems like pgbackups is using `pg_dump` internally, though there may be additional things going on as well. The docs indicate that the output is essentially the same as this `pg_dump` command.

```sh
pg_dump -F c --no-acl --no-owner --quote-all-identifiers $DATABASE_URL
```

Attempting to run migrations during the backup window has repeatedly caused me some pain, as the migrations lock up and hang. To mitigate this, I'd like to detect when the backups are running, and avoid running the migrations by having a pre-check in the script that runs the migrations.

I can do this by checking with Heroku's CLI, and that will work for my current specifics, but I'm wondering if something less specific to Heroku might be reasonable, by watching for a running `pg_dump` instead.

Is there a good way to detect if `pg_dump` is currently running, and may block schema changes?

Answer (score 1):

Unless somebody has overridden the `application_name` parameter for `pg_dump`, you could do this:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE application_name = 'pg_dump';
```

If that gives you 0, no `pg_dump` is running.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, they've either overridden the name, or they're using some more internal method to do the backup, because it has the name "Heroku Postgres Backup". It makes me wonder if `pg_dump` would even be a major block on schema migrations the way Heroku backups are.

Comment: Yes, `pg_dump` would block `ALTER TABLE` (or vice versa). You cannot read from a table and have it grow another column in the middle of reading. If that Heroku dump is running `SELECT` statements, it is akin to `pg_dump`.